# Diameter of finite union.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $(U_i)_i^k$ is a finite collection of sets such that $diam(U_i)\leq M$ for each $i\in I$.

$diam(\bigcup_i^k U_i)$ $<$ $\sum_{i=1}^k diam(U_i)$?

Is in general not true, take $[0,1]\cup [2,5]$ the total diameter is 5 <1+3=4.

So my question is, what would be a relationship be between $diam(\bigcup_i^k U_i)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k diam(U_i)$?

Comment: None...........

Comment: The max of the diameters of the $U_i$ is $\le$ the diameter of the union, trivially. Sum is unclear. No inequality either way in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $U_i$ can be disjoint and far apart.. In that case the union will have a far larger diameter than the simple sum.

Trivial example: the diameters of sets $\{0\}, \ldots, \{n\}$ are all $0$, but the union has diameter $n = |0-n|$. You can vary on this for more examples.

If $U_1 \cap U_2 \neq \emptyset$ and also $U_2 \cap U_3 \neq \emptyset$, etc. with the triangle inequality you can find some sum bounds on the union...